# Allow cross domain access on Rails server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, server, request

I have a front end web app in Angular and back end in Rails. 
From front-end I have javascript code issuing POST http request:

```
$scope.onSave = function () {
        $http.post('http://localhost:3000/documents', { user: $scope.user, formData: $scope.formData }, function (response) {
            $scope.isSaved = true;
            console.log(response);
            if (response.success) {
                console.log("It has been successfully saved!")
            }
        });
}
```

And on submit button, I call above function:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="onSave()">Submit</button>
```

Then I get an error saying

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/documents. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I know i need to allow cross domain access but I'm not sure how I can achieve this in Rails server side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add  [this](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) `gem "rack-cors"` to your Gemfile.
2. Add this to your config/application.rb file.

```
   config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
        allow do
            origins '*'
            resource '*',
              headers: :any,
              methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :delete, :put, :options]
        end
    end
```

Comment: Sweet this works. Could using this cause any type of security loop hole by any chance?

Comment: Yes absolutely, you should at least restrict the domains and ports you want to expose in a whitelist. '*' means open to everyone which is not good

Comment: For example, if I just wanna allow a request coming from "www.example.com", then I just need to add that URl to the configuration file like origins 'www.example.com', right? I'm not sure what I need to configure for resource tho.

Comment: Yes, see this article for reference. https://demisx.github.io/rails-api/2014/02/18/configure-accept-headers-cors.html

Comment: For Rails 5+ use Rack::Cors instead of "Rack::Cors"

Answer (score 1):

I had a need to query multiple APIs running on the same server with different port addresses.  I have been playing around with using an "Ajax" controller that just passes through the requests via `HTTParty` and renders the response in JSON:

```
class AjaxController < ApplicationController

   def query
     port = params['port']
     path = params['path']
     url = "http://0.0.0.0:#{port}/#{path}"
     response = HTTParty.get(url)
     render json: response
   end

end
```

The query is scripted (for example):

```
 <script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.plans;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/ajax/query?port=3005&path=items.json?state=TX",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Obviously this approach needs to be secured, but perhaps it will yield some further ideas.